# Protobuf.js: the Writer doesn't seems to `finish`

Tags: typescript, rest, protocol-buffers, protobufjs

I'm encountering a weird bug while using Protobuf in my TypeScript frontend. I'm using Axios to make calls to my REST API and the protobuf.js package to handle Protobuf in my frontend. I'm new to protobuf, and the issue may stem from my lack of knowledge.

The problem arises when I'm making multiple calls to my API with a payload.

For example, I want to post 3 objects: `object_1`, `object_2`, and `object_3`. Hence, I'm making three post requests. The first request is always correctly handled—`object_1` is added to the backend. However, the following ones, to post `object_2` and `object_3`, are posting `object_1` again. I've investigated the issue and found that my protobuf is appended to the payload. Meaning that I've got `object_1`, and `object_2` in the second request's payload and `object_1`, `object_2`, and `object_3` in the third request's payload. My API only reads the first protobuf, i.e., `object_1` and adds three times `object_1`.

I'm using the protobuf.js package as stated in the documentation:

```
const message = Message.create({ message: 'hello' });
const buffer = Message.encode(message).finish();
await axios.post([...] message [...]);
```

Does anyone already confront this issue? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Writer object of protobufjs uses a shared array buffer.

But axios post doesn't look for the byteOffset and byteLength properties and uses the entire shared buffer, not just the bytes you want.

You can extract the relevant bytes like this:

```js
const message = Message.create({ message: 'hello' });
const x = Message.encode(message).finish();
const buffer = new Uint8Array(x.buffer, x.byteOffset, x.byteLength);
```

In my opinion, protobufjs is a bit dated. This is a shameless plug, because I am the author, but if you are not happy with protobufjs, please have a look at [protobuf-ts](https://github.com/timostamm/protobuf-ts). You would encode your message to binary like this:

```js
const message = Message.create({ message: 'hello' });
const bytes: Uint8Array = Message.toBinary(message);
```

It also [supports Angular](https://github.com/timostamm/protobuf-ts/blob/ea15636b16ab982e2596dd0e0b4f11972e60cbbc/MANUAL.md#angular-support) with auto-generated Twirp clients.

Comment: Thank you! I was already using protobuf-ts, but I wanted to know why some old code in this project at work (which formerly used protobuf-js) was performing modifications on UInt8Array messages before packing them into a request body. Glad I'm using protobuf-ts.